# 'int' object has no attribute 'replace' error in python3.x

Tags: pandas, web-scraping

I don't get why this error occurs. Coz from my point of view the three columns 'WWBO','IBO','DBO' has exact same structure but when I apply 'replace' only WWBO works. Does it have sth with fillna?
Need your help!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

#Read url
URL = "https://www.the-numbers.com/box-office-records/worldwide/all-            movies/cumulative/released-in-2019"
data = requests.get(URL).text

#parse url
soup = bs(data, "html.parser")

#find the tables you want
table = soup.findAll("table")[1:]

#read it into pandas
df = pd.read_html(str(table))

#concat both the tables
df = pd.concat([df[0],df[1]])
df = df.rename(columns={'Rank':'Rank',
             'Movie':'Title',
             'Worldwide Box Office':'WWBO',
             'Domestic Box Office':'DBO',
             'International Box Office':'IBO',
             'DomesticShare':'Share'})

#drop columns
market = df.drop(columns=['Rank','Share'])
market = market.fillna(0)

#replace $ -> '' 
market['WWBO'] = market['WWBO'].map(lambda s: s.replace('$',''))
market['IBO'] = market['IBO'].map(lambda s: s.replace('$',''))
market['DBO'] = market['DBO'].map(lambda s: s.replace('$',''))

market
```

Error is:::
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is Pandas bugs auto casting '0' values to int, to solutions for this either eliminate the 0 value or cast the columns to string as below

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

#Read url
URL = "https://www.the-numbers.com/box-office-records/worldwide/all-movies/cumulative/released-in-2019"
data = requests.get(URL).text

#parse url
soup = bs(data, "html.parser")

#find the tables you want
table = soup.findAll("table")[1:]

#read it into pandas
df = pd.read_html(str(table))

#concat both the tables
df = pd.concat([df[0],df[1]])
df = df.rename(columns={'Rank':'Rank',
             'Movie':'Title',
             'Worldwide Box Office':'WWBO',
             'Domestic Box Office':'DBO',
             'International Box Office':'IBO',
             'DomesticShare':'Share'})

#drop columns
market = df.drop(columns=['Rank','Share'])
market = market.fillna(0)

#replace $ -> '' 
market['WWBO'] = market['WWBO'].map(lambda s: s.replace('$',''))
market['IBO']=market['IBO'].astype(str)
market['IBO'] = market['IBO'].map(lambda s: s.replace('$',''))
market['DBO']=market['DBO'].astype(str)
market['DBO'] = market['DBO'].map(lambda s: s.replace('$',''))

>> market[['WWBO','IBO','DBO']]
       WWBO            IBO          DBO
0   2,622,240,021  1,842,814,023  779,425,998
1   1,121,905,659    696,535,598  425,370,061
2     692,163,684    692,163,684            0
3     518,883,574    358,491,094  160,392,480
4     402,976,036    317,265,826   85,710,210
5     358,234,705    220,034,625  138,200,080
6     342,904,508    231,276,537  111,627,971
7     326,150,303    326,150,303            0
8     293,766,097    192,548,368  101,217,729
9     255,832,826    255,832,826            0
10    253,940,650     79,203,380  174,737,270
11    245,303,505    134,268,500  111,035,005
12    190,454,964     84,648,456  105,806,508
13    155,313,390     98,312,634   57,000,756
```

Comment: Oh good lord that was annoying, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

clearly one or more of these fields(**market['WWBO'], market['IBO'], market['DBO']**) have integer values and you are trying to perform string operation i.e. replace over it that's it is throwing error that

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'

could you first print those values and see what are they or if you have many then its better to perform type check first like

```
if market['WWBO'].dtype == object:
    market['WWBO'].map(lambda s: s.replace('$',''))
else:
    pass
```

let me know if this works for you or not